# Name any misssions which were conducted due to urgency or due to some emergency in a very limited time?

Tags: history, mission-design

I would like to know if there were any space missions which were conducted due to an immediate emergency and I wish to know how they were managed.

Comment: This question is very broad.  Have you done any research?  Are you referring to emergencies in/on vehicles in  orbit ?

Comment: One category would be something launched specifically to assist something else already in space, but would you consider answers based on moving an orbiting spacecraft from one orbit to another (or rescheduling it's observations) in order to *image* another spacecraft?

Comment: Conducting an entire mission due to an emergency...the current state of things is that it takes a long time to prep for a mIssion. Late in the shuttle program, a rescue mission was planned & prepped for the last Hubble repair flight but it turned out not to be needed. A long analysis was done after the fact about whether the STS-107 crew could have been rescued - there is a question about that already. Content of missions have been changed at the last minute e.g. Skylab repair. But spin up a whole new mission? I don't think so. I'm assuming you're asking about crewed missions.

Comment: thanks @OrganicMarble your words were something I was looking for

Comment: There has been a Space Shuttle mission in the 1990s that had to be aborted and was repeated very soon, the same crew flew to space again and conducted the mission. I dunno what the two flights were called like, but that's the only such case I think that happened. Perhaps there were more "Shuttle repeat missions" like that.